# Show exact time with GMT JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

The given time is in a format of ISO_8601 
E.g: "2019-04-05T13:30-05:00"
E.g: "2005-08-09T18:31+03:30"
should return an exact time in a readable format with the GMT which is mentioned
E.g. Sat, Nov 30, 2019, 11:00 PM GMT+1

Input: "2019-04-05T13:30-05:00"
Output: "FRI, APR 5, 2019, 1:30 PM GMT-5"

Input: "2005-08-09T18:31+03:30"
Output: "TUE, AUG 9, 2005, 6:31 PM GMT+3"

Comment: The second example GMT+3? isn't it supposed to be GMT+3:30?

Comment: @Ali Yes. I believe you are right it should be "GMT+3:30"

Comment: There are already many questions and good answers on [*how to format a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date). Try something, and if you have issues, post the code and ask for help rather than just asking for someone to write the code for you.

Comment: @user116313—For what value of "should"? ISO 8601 allows +3, +0300 or +03:00. [*ECMAScript*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) requires +03:00. So +3:00 is the only format **not** supported by either ISO 8601 or ECMA-262.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), here is a simple snippet how to do it with moment.

```js
function getDateString(inputDate) {
  let date = moment.parseZone(inputDate);

  return date.format('ddd, MMM D, YYYY, h:mm A zZ')
}

console.log(getDateString("2005-08-09T18:31+03:30"));
console.log(getDateString("2019-04-05T13:30-05:00"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, actually, this worked for me

 `code`getTime (inputDate) {
      const data = this.$moment.parseZone(inputDate).format('ddd, MMM D, YYYY, h:mm A [GMT]Z')
      return data
    }